# Ambient Occlusion and Volumetric Lighting

Tags: light, lighting

I am right now doing an interior scene for a customer. For trying out some stuff I thought about volumetric light. Unfortunately I can't get it to work thought I used it before successfully. My thought was, that the ambient occlusion got something to do with it. But even turning AO off won't show the known volumetric effect.
Since the scene is quite huge and has a LOT of linked objects I can't share it that easily. 
Now this is no must have and I am short on time and I am just curious - I won't try out a lot (later perhaps) and therefor just asking  :)
Does anyone know anything about an interaction between these two?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If turning off AO doesn't allow you to preview volumetrics why do you think AO is somehow involved? It's hard to judge only on description, at least some screenshots could make it easier. For now the only detail in your question about actually problem is *"I can't get it to work though I used it before successfully"* which is quite vague - *what* doesn't work?

Comment: You don't have to necessarily use images from your project. Try to reproduce a basic scene and use that, maybe you might even solve your problem in doing this. See this meta post on how to better ask questions - https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/608/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-is-hard-to-describe/609#609

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not precise, sorry about that. Asked out of curiosity if anyone knows something. I will get back to it and will try to reproduce it when I got more time.

Comment: I doubt AO is an issue, but  it is hard to tell. **Your question is likely to get closed as unclear** unless you [edit] the contents and add some information that is useful to solve your problem. Start by stating which render engine you are using. Create a simplified scene that you can show and share, that shows the problem clearly.